# Display in bash prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bash, rvm, command-prompt

I am working with bash and still unfamiliar with the difference between `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`.

My desired result is to have the ruby version and `rvm gemset` show up on my bash prompt.

I added `PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1"` to .bash_profile (via xcode) and it displays

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286 John-MacBook-Air:~ john$
```

What I trying to get is

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3 $
```

With "rails3" being the output of `rvm gemset`.

**How do I get `John-MacBook-Air:~ john` removed from the prompt?**

I tried adding the line in the .profile, and .bashrc with no luck but it seems to work in the .bash_profile.  Any clarification between these files would be greatly appreciated.  I am running rvm on a Mac.

**SOLUTION**

include the following to the .bash_profile

```
PS1='\W \$ '
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1"
```

the prompt looks like

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails3 ~ $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1"
```

What you're saying there is "add my rvm prompt to PS1" and then put the pre-existing `PS1` at the end. The system's default `PS1` is setting this:

```
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
```

In that setting `\h` is the hostname (here 'John-MacBook-Air'), `\W` is the current working directory with your home directory abbreviated to `~`, `\u` is your user's login name (here 'john') and `\$` will show a dollar sign if you are a regular user and an octothorpe (`#`) if you're logged in as root. On OSX, that is set by default in `/etc/bashrc`. If you want to change the prompt, you need to customize the latter part of the prompt rather than just re-entering `$PS1` as is back into the new setting. Removing the hostname is common, but I would very strongly recommend *against* removing the current working directory. It's very useful information when in a terminal session. Just my two cents.

To see what you can put there, take a look for information about [setting your prompt in Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the advice on keeping the working directory, I am beginning to see its usefulness and importance.  I have added my solution to the original question post.

Answer (score 2):

> I am working with bash and still unfamiliar with the difference between .profile, .bashrc, .bash_profile.

That depends on your system configuration. Read the manpage for that. You can also change the behaviour either system- or userwide by including one from the other.

Here are few notes to understand better.

- **Per-login initialization.** (or: session startup) There are startup files which are only executed for login shells. On my system, they only set environment variables. (That makes sense, because environment variables are inherited).
  Those may be called `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` for plain `sh`. If `bash` is your shell and you have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`, it will prefer those (in this order) instead by default.
  Note that changes to session startup files have no effect until you login next time. Also, you need to make sure to export variables to the environment like `PS1=something ; export PS1`.
- **Per-process initialization.** For Plain `sh`, there is no default per-process initialization file, but you can set the `ENV` environment variable to point to one. For `bash`, there is also the `BASH_ENV` variable, and the `~/.bashrc` file. The per-process initialization file is the place where you can store per-process shell settings (those who can't be inherited through the environment), e.g. aliases or function definitions.

If you just want to see if a particular file is executed, you can always echo something, or touch some file like `echo TEST` or `touch /tmp/test`.